# How lexical scope affects lambda function?

Tags: racket

This is an example of the Racket tutorial.

```
(define (square n)
  (filled-rectangle n n))

(define series
  (lambda (mk)
    (hc-append 4 (mk 5)(mk 10)(mk 20))))

(define (rgb-series mk)
  (vc-append
   (series (lambda (sz) (colorize (mk sz) "red")))
   (series (lambda (sz) (colorize (mk sz) "green")))
   (series (lambda (sz) (colorize (mk sz) "blue")))))

(define (rgb-maker mk)
  (lambda (sz)
    (vc-append (colorize (mk sz) "red")
               (colorize (mk sz) "green")
               (colorize (mk sz) "blue"))))
```

I think the function rgb-series and rgb-maker are doing the same thing. However, their outputs are quite different.

[image]

I could not figure out why.  Could anyone explain what's the difference between two functions? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference lies in how `vc-append` and `hc-append` are applied.

When you create a row of picts using `hc-append`, these picts are arranged [h]orizontally, [c]entre aligned. For example:

[image]

Now you can stack three such rows into a column using `vc-append`, forming the following final pict:

[image]

This is what is happening in `rgb-series`, whereby rows are first created, *then* stacked into a column.

On the other hand, `(series (rgb-maker circle))` first creates a column of circles, *then* arranges these columns into a row, which would look as follows:

[image]